# how can I get Excel to show the values in a complex formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I can get the values to show in a simple formula like A19+A20, but what a about a more complex formula?

The formula I'm working with is this: =(A19+A20)/(1-A15).  I have one cell where the answer to the formula is shown, but next to it, I want the formula to be displayed with the values showing instead of the cell references. So, for example, I would like the cell to show: (1+2)/(1-.63)

Is this possible to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use concatenate to do this.

```
=CONCATENATE("(",A19,"+",A20,")/(1-",A15,")")
```

Edit: I don't know if there's an automated way Excel would do this for you, but this way will get messy for super complicated formula.

If you don't need to see value of the column all the time, you can click on the `Formula` tab, and go to `Evaluate Formula` and that'll show you the whole process on how the result was calculated.